# What is the relationship between eps and the number of features considered by the regularization model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regularized

I observed that as I adjust the eps parameter downwards, the model considers more variables (i.e. less variables have a coef of zero). Is there an explanation for this trend?

**Figure 1: eps == 0.001**

[image]

**Figure 2: eps == 0.0001**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ElasticNetCV` calculates a *regularization path* `[min_alpha, max_alpha]` of length `n_alphas` and runs cross-validation to determine the best `alpha`. Here, `max_alpha` is the value for which `ElasticNet` produces all-zero solution, and `min_alpha` equals `eps * max_alpha`. So, for smaller `alpha`s we expect fewer zero coefficients as the objective `Loss + min_alpha * Regularization` approaches ordinary least squares.